# EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir /test NodeJS

Tags: node.js, file, createfile

I'm trying to create a directory in the root directory of the system i.e. the `~` on mac which holds the global `node_modules`, documents folder, desktop folder etc. I believe it's `c:` on windows. Here's the problem:

I want to create a directory there, like `~/SOME_DIR/ANOTHER_DIR/MY_FILE`.
Now, when I try to create a directory there here's the error:

```
{
    "status": "fail",
    "err": {
        "errno": -30,
        "code": "EROFS",
        "syscall": "mkdir",
        "path": "/test"
    },
    "error": "EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/test'"
}
```

Here's my code which executes when a person hits a route:

```
        fs.mkdir('/test', (err) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    status: 'fail',
                    err,
                    error: err.message,
                });
            }
        });
```

I'm open to using other packages. Any help/guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Unprivileged code generally cannot write anything to the root directories of file systems because file-system security prevents it. That's the cause of the error you see.

Comment: Ok thanks, Is there a way to get around it? By asking for permission like what we have in chrome to access user location, camera etc?

Comment: On a host computer you control, you can change file system protections to allow the user under which you run your nodejs program to write to the root directory.  You will not be able to do this on any server computer facing the public internet, however. The ability for web server software to write to root directories makes the host system extremely vulnerable to cybercreeps. Suggest you rethink this design.